# Finding the value of a node in a Haskell tree

Tags: haskell, tree, algebraic-data-types

I am currently messing with some Haskell trees. I am new to Haskell (coming from C) and am wondering how I can find the individual value of a Node (what I've been calling a leaf) from the tree.
If my tree is say:
    (root) power, (branchLeft) 2, (branchRight) 3

If I want to read this as, 2 to the power of three, how should I go about this?
I'm starting from scratch and have been messing with code now for the past 3 hours and have not got very far.

Any tips/ideas?

Comment: Can you please include your data model? Is it a binary tree?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can model a binary tree with a binary operator in the inner nodes using an algebraic data type:

```
data Tree a = Leaf a | InnerNode (a -> a -> a) (Tree a) (Tree a)
```

The function `a -> a -> a` is the binary operator. For example, a simple tree of integers could be defined as

```
tree :: Tree Integer
tree = InnerNode (+) (InnerNode (^) (Leaf 3) (Leaf 2)) (Leaf 5)
```

To evaluate or *interpret* the tree in the way you describe you can write a function

```
interpretTree :: Tree Integer -> Integer
```

To write that function, you will probably want to use pattern matching and recursion:

```
interpretTree (Leaf x) = x           -- the base case
interpretTree (InnerNode f l r) = ...  -- use recursion here
```

For the second case, you can recursively compute the results for the subtrees and combine them using the function `f`.

Answer (score 1):

I'll define a data type along the lines you mentioned:

```
data Tree2 b a = Leaf a | Node b (Tree2 b a) (Tree2 b a)
  deriving Show
```

so I'll be able to use

```
example :: Tree2 (Integer -> Integer -> Integer) Integer 
example = Node (^) (Leaf 2) (Leaf 3)
```

The most general folding function ("catamorphism") you can make on this type is one which recurses down the structure replacing each constructor (`Leaf`, `Node`) with a function (`foldLeaf`, `foldNode`):

```
foldTree2 :: (a -> v) -> (b -> v -> v -> v) -> Tree2 b a -> v
foldTree2 foldLeaf foldNode = fold where 
   fold (Leaf a) = foldLeaf a
   fold (Node b left right) 
                 = foldNode b (fold left) (fold right)
```

so we should be able to define lots of functions using this, but in particular, the evaluation function you were seeking is

```
inOrderApply :: Tree2 (a -> a -> a) a -> a
inOrderApply = foldTree2 id id
```

```
ghci> inOrderApply example
8
ghci> inOrderApply (Node (+) (Node (-) (Leaf 10) (Leaf 5))  (Node (*) (Leaf 3) (Leaf 2)))
11
```